# Fedora install nex to windows and 0 free space available

Tags: fedora

I have a problem with the installation of Fedora 20 next to windows 8.1. I converted the disk to GPT. Here is a screen of the program GParted
[image]

When I select the drive in the installer gets something like this:

[image]
[image]
http://www.picresize.com/popup.html?images/rsz_screenshot_from_2014-11-05_113337.png

[image]
And I can not start the installation. I tried manually create mount point, but it did not help. When you select the automatic mount points gets the error: failed to find a Suitable stage1 device. I do not know what to do ...

EDIT: I installed from USB

Comment: what does the warning icon next to /dev/sda2 tell?

Comment: nothing, nothing shows

Comment: Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot install grub2 on LVM partition

in fedora installer use custom partition and select standard partition for root mount point or preferably make a 300~500MB standard partition formatted as ext4
and select it as `/boot` in fedora installer

also you will need to make `biosboot` partition if you want to boot from a GPT disk on non-UEFI system

Comment: I chose a standard partition, but nothing has changed.I added the same /boot but it also did not help anything. What to do with the bios boot?

Comment: in fedora installer custom partitioning page click on add button and in first drop-down-menu select biosboot; if this didn't help go to installation destination page and click on error message on the bottom of the page and take an screenshot of error message

Comment: I get an error:  failed to find a Suitable stage1 device.

Comment: Which in this case can I do?

Comment: Ali AlipourR: any ideas?

Comment: stage 1 is grub boot sector so it cannot install grub boot sector; 
I'm Curious why you converted a 256GB disk to GPT! always use MBR unless you know you should use GPT;1-do you tested creating `biosboot` and `/boot` partition in fedora installer? (at same time,you should have three mount points: biosboot + /boot (ext4) + / (lvm or ext4)) 2-what is your device model? 3-you are booting in UEFI-only mode or BIOS-only mode or hybrid(CSM) mode?

Comment: I've read that GPT is faster, so I did. How do you think I should do? To convert to mbr? Is it possible to leave only one partition on a GPT and the other on the MBR. Yes, the drive has 256GB SSD. biosboot + / boot (ext4) + / (ext4) did not help. I'm booting in UEFI-only mode.

Comment: for ssd generally MBR is better; also if you installed Windows in MBR mode i doubt that it would properly boot after converting disk to GPT in booting in UEFI-only mode ... you can convert disk to MBR with `gdisk` but I do not recommend it, you are better off setting your Boot mode to CSM or BIOS and boot a live cd and create new partition table and leave 2MiB free at beginning of disk and then make a 500MB partition for /boot and a partition for Windows and one for Fedora then install Windows which will use that 500MB partition as its boot partition(system-reserved)

Comment: then install fedora and select that 500MB partition for /boot and format it as ext4, gurb2 installer usually will automatically detect Windows installation and will add it to boot menu

Comment: I do not know why, but as I turned off the UEFI everything went well!! I convert to GPT disk before installing Windows, but now the partition manager shows me that the disk is MBR do not know why.